# freebsd ec2-user sftp amazon ec2 console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, freebsd

I have tried to use winscp to log into my server. I haven't successfully logged into the server. I keep getting error messages [image]

I need to drop an sql file to the server. when i use winscp to log into my freebsd instance, i get a password prompt for my ec2 key. i was wondering if you should set a password for the ec2-user. the server was launched from amazon ec2 aws console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I had to issue the following command.

```
sudo passwd ec2-user
```

or

```
su 

passwd ec2-user
```

It ended up working.